# Webview scroll and transparent layer

Tags: ios, uiwebview, iscroll

I am developing a web application on iOS using uiwebview. 
See this image.

[image]

I have a UIWebview and let them be scrollable using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

The problem is,
menu bar is a rectangle which have some transparent area.
(left upper side in this image). 
I expected in the Transparent Area, I can see underlying content.
But, in the transparent area, I can not see the scrollable content.
The area just show webview's background image.(from objective-c).

is this impossible to display fixed and curved-shape menu bar on top of scrollable content? 

should I have to make it using objective-c code not web languages?

Comment: The black arrow direction is a little confusing. Are you creating the menu with html too ?

Comment: yes, it's html. uiwebview with fullscreen.

Comment: Did you compare the page appearance with any desktop browser ? That seems to be the html problem, not UIWebView. The huge disadvantage of using two webViews (as i understood "using objective-c code") to add the menu over the main content is that the transparent menu part will block the page interaction and that frame is large if that's a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for myself.

use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) for scrollable view first.

And then make 0*0 pixel size div(position relative).

put the menu bar in the div using absolute position.

It should work well~ ^^;